# Check if tables are identical using SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I was asked this question during an interview for a Junior Oracle Developer position, the interviewer admitted it was a tough one:

Write a query/queries to check if the table 'employees_hist' is an exact copy of the table 'employees'.  Any ideas how to go about this?

EDIT: Consider that tables can have duplicate records so a simple MINUS will not work in this case.

EXAMPLE

```
EMPLOYEES

NAME
--------
Jack Crack
Jack Crack
Jill Hill
```

These two would not be identical.

```
EMPLOYEES_HIST

NAME
--------
Jack Crack
Jill Hill
Jill Hill
```

Comment: What did he say when you asked him whether he meant the meta-data or the data in the tables?

Comment: @popovitsj the data.

Comment: Instead of flooding all the answers as incorrect, why don't you post a test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, which caters for duplicates, is to create a subquery which does a UNION on the two tables, and includes the number of duplicates contained within each table by grouping on all the columns. The outer query can then group on all the columns, including the row count column. If the table match, there should be no rows returned:

```
create table employees (name varchar2(100));
create table employees_hist (name varchar2(100));

insert into employees values ('Jack Crack');
insert into employees values ('Jack Crack');
insert into employees values ('Jill Hill');
insert into employees_hist values ('Jack Crack');
insert into employees_hist values ('Jill Hill');
insert into employees_hist values ('Jill Hill');


with both_tables as
(select name, count(*) as row_count
 from employees
 group by name
union all
 select name, count(*) as row_count
 from employees_hist
 group by name)
select name, row_count from both_tables
group by name, row_count having count(*) <> 2;
```

gives you:

```
Name        Row_count
Jack Crack  1
Jack Crack  2
Jill Hill   1
Jill Hill   2
```

This tells you that both names appear once in one table and twice in the other, and therefore the tables don't match.

Comment: This answer fails as well if there's duplicate data.

Comment: Yes, I said that in my answer. I don't think it's entirely unreasonable to assume that the tables will have primary keys

Comment: OK so the OP edited the question and now it IS entirely unreasonable to assume there won't be duplicate records. :)

Comment: Updated to cater for duplicates in one or both tables.

Answer (score 5):

If the tables have the same columns, you can use this; this will return no rows if the rows in both tables are identical:

```
(
select * from test_data_01
minus
select * from test_data_02
)
union
(
select * from test_data_02
minus
select * from test_data_01
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Identical regarding what? Metadata or the actual table data too?

Anyway, use `MINUS`.

```
select * from table_1
MINUS
select * from table_2
```

So, if the two tables are really identical, i.e. the metadata and the actual data, it would return no rows. Else, it would prove that the data is different.

If, you receive an error, it would mean the metadata itself is different.

**Update** If the data is not same, and that one of the table has duplicates.

Just select the unique records from one of the table, and simply apply `MINUS` against the other table.

Comment: This is wrong, MINUS returns only unique rows, what if one table has duplicate records and the other doesn't.

Comment: Did OP mention about the difference in the data? Why do you assume it? Ok, so you are the OP it seems. Please elaborate your requirement in the question, I or someone else would definitely help you.

Comment: You need to check if the two tables are exactly the same, duplicate records can always exist in a table.

Comment: Then just select only unique records from one of the table and then do the MINUS.

Comment: If employees has records 1, 1, 3 and employees_hist has records 1, 3, 3 then they are not identical.

Comment: Then the tables are not same per the data. Only metadata is identical. If values are different, then identical word is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong word, I edited my post to add an example.

Comment: Ok, I saw your edit. I still say, just select unique rows from the table and apply minus. Did you try doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63507/discussion-between-lalit-kumar-b-and-user2321926).

Comment: MINUS is the wrong approach, for the reason already specified in the first comment on this answer. Selecting unique rows just ignores the duplicates, it doesn't make the problem go away.

Comment: @Bacs, Go by the original question, and then follow the comments. And then , elucidate.

Comment: Set up the test tables and test your answer. You can use the script in my answer. Your answer will return no rows, because the second table contains no unique rows that are not in the first table. However the tables clearly do not match.

Comment: This is a very good answer when you don't care about whole duplicate records. So, when you want to know whether ALL the information is in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, count(*) n from EMPLOYEES group by name
minus
select name, count(*) n from EMPLOYEES_HIST group by name
union all ( 
select name, count(*) n from EMPLOYEES_HIST group by name
minus
select name, count(*) n from EMPLOYEES group by name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the two tables and then subtract one of the tables from the result. If the result of the subtraction is an empty table then you know that the the tables must be the same since merge had no effect (every row and column were effectively the same)

[How do I merge two tables with different column number while removing duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172577/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-with-different-column-number-while-removing-duplicates)

That link provides a good way to merge the two tables without duplicates without knowing what the columns are.

Comment: Why unnecessary `DML`?

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number to make sure there are no duplicate rows. Now you can use minus and if there are no results, the tables are identical.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By Name), *
FROM tab1
MINUS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By Name), *
FROM tab2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not get the job . Check the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the rows are unique by adding a pseudo column

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT <All_Columns>
        , row_number() OVER
            (PARTITION BY <All_Columns>
             ORDER BY <All_Columns>) row_num
   FROM employees)
, t2 AS
  (SELECT <All_Columns>
        , row_number() OVER
            (PARTITION BY <All_Columns>
             ORDER BY <All_Columns>) row_num
   FROM employees_hist)
(SELECT *
 FROM t1
 MINUS
 SELECT *
 FROM t2
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM t1
 MINUS
 SELECT *
 FROM t2)
```

Comment: @LalitKumarB you said to "just select unique rows from the table". However, there are not unique rows in the table so you have to make them unique somehow; I added a row number to do this. If this is what you were suggesting it is not very clear from your comments; nowhere do you state to add another column to make the rows unique.

Comment: I bet, we both are pointing to same solution, however, OP seems to be confused ;-)