# Alternate method for replacing Minus,Union All,Intersect operators in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, union-all, subquery

I have to compare data from two tables .Currently there is stored procedure where the logic of procedure comes as 
selecting 1st table data minus 2nd table data and vice versa.If the count matches its just hard-coding a message as "Matched" else "Unmatched"

My doubt:
Can I change the logic of the Procedure with other than Minus operators ?
any suggestions?

```
select count(*) into t1 from c1;
select count(*) into t2 from c2;
select count(*) into t3 from(
   select a1,a2,a3 from c1
      minus
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2);
select count(*) into t4 from(
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2
      minus
     select a1,a2,a3 from c1);

select count(*) into t5 from(
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2
      Intersect
     select a1,a2,a3 from c1);

Insert into A1 
SELECT t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,(CASE WHEN T4=0 THEN ‘MATCHED’
                                        ELSE ‘NOT MTACHED’
                                         END) STATUS ,’ ‘
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: If the set operators are working, why do you want to change it?

Comment: What does it look like.

Comment: @tbone yes set operators are absolutely working I just want to try some advance method that can increase the performance much better

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to outperform set operators in most situations.  But post the code, lets see

Comment: @tbone I am giving the skeleton of the code since its project specific.

Comment: select count(*) into t1 from c1;
select count(*) into t2 from c2;
select count(*) into t3 from(
     select a1,a2,a3 from c1
      minus
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2);
select count(*) into t4 from(
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2
      minus
     select a1,a2,a3 from c1);

select count(*) into t5 from(
     select a1,a2,a3 from c2
      Intersect
     select a1,a2,a3 from c1);

Insert into A1 
SELECT t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,(CASE WHEN T4=0 THEN ‘MATCHED’
                                        ELSE ‘NOT MTACHED’
                                         END) STATUS ,’ ‘
FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

Count rows that occur only in one of the 2 tables.
If count is 0, you have a match.

```
SELECT decode(count (*), 0, 'MATCH', 'NO MATCH')
FROM T_1
FULL OUTER JOIN T_2
    ON T_1.a = T_2.a AND T_1.b = T_2.b /* List all colums */
WHERE T_1.a IS NULL
   OR T_2.a IS NULL;
```

T_1.a and T_2.a are keys and NOT NULL.

Comment: will be there any performance issue by using the above query?

Answer (score 0):

Counting rows from both tables and using `minus` twice seems to be enough, I didn't imagine scenario where `intersect` finds something new. There is however situation where tables are different and your queries show `MATCHED`:

```
with 
  t1(a1, a2, a3) as (
    select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
    select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 2, 2 from dual  ),
  t2(a1, a2, a3) as (
    select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 2, 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 2, 2 from dual  )
select a1, a2, a3 from t1 intersect select a1, a2, a3 from t2
```

Both `minus` show empty result, rows counts are equal, intersect shows 2 rows and this tells us nothing. [Here is similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511527/check-if-tables-are-identical-using-sql-in-oracle) to yours, please read answers there. But you need to group and count data, so this will be even slower than what you do now.

If duplicated rows are not issue, then Peter's answer looks promising.