# Is there a way to combine a series of tables that may have no columns in common

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I have a cluster of 3000 tables that I need to combine into a master table that includes all rows of data. Across these 3000 tables there are 500 distinct columns. 1 individual table might only have 10 / 500 columns, but I need a way to query across these tables to pull a columns values if that table has the column or return null if it doesn't so the end result stacks all data on top of each other like so.

```
Table | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | ... | Column 499 | Column 500
Table1| Value    | Value    | Value    | ... | Null       | Null
Table2| Null     | Null     | Value    | ... | Value      | Value
```

Comment: Can you do a `Left/Right Join` on each of the tables? It seems like a heavy query to be joining on 3000 tables.

Comment: @CameronTinker I'm less trying to join the data because it would be very difficult to find values to join on. The general idea is I want to stack all rows of each table using a union statement. So the crux of the problem is how do I union a bunch of tables that might be completely different.

Comment: How? You examine / evaluate the structure of each table, translate that information into a matrix (of ids/datatypes) and then write the union code to accomplish that. Given the enormous number of tables and columns, you will likely struggle to do that. Some automation might be possible using dynamic sql and making many assumptions - but that is likely beyond your abilities. Perhaps you might leverage skills in Excel or Access to assist you in writing your tsql. Suggest you just try it with a small example for a proof.

Comment: *"I want to stack all rows of each table using a union statement."* Then the tables will need to have identical definitions, which you explicitly say they don't.

Comment: 3000 tables? Poor database design I guess.

Comment: Also, do you *really* have a table with 500~ columns? If so, you have some significant design flaws, in my opinion. Just because a table *can* have 1,024 columns, doesn't mean they should (have any near) that many columns.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172577/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-with-different-column-number-while-removing-duplicates

Comment: @SMor I took your advice and leveraged my Excel to figure this problem out. I queried the system tables to get a list of the tables and all columns associated with each table then built it out like a Matrix in excel with tables going vertical and the columns going across. Then I put in a formula in the matrix to check against the list of tables and column and if both match return the column name and if not return null. I'm going to use this to build out a union statement.